# Remaining tire life estimate

Tags: tire

I am looking for a ballpark estimate as to how many miles I have left on this rear tire:

[image]

Comment: It's hardly worn at all.

Comment: More than you think. But ultimately, it's always a judgement call when the frequency of punctures becomes too high.

Comment: For traction off road riding, 0 miles left, for on road riding,  quite a lot, depends how often you skid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you get a lot of punctures while riding?  I got a puncture every month or two while commuting.  When that suddenly increased to a weekly puncture, it becomes time for new tyres.  It was 80% the rear wheel.

I can still see the central tread line in the middle of your tyre, so it looks perfectly fine to keep riding IMO.   Also, its probably got a little faster as the central knobs wear off, assuming you ride smoother roads.

If you're riding off-road aggressively (ie competitively), then the lack of central tread may become more important.

When punctures get more common suddenly, then replace both tyres.

**Estimate**: 500-1500 km, (300-900 miles)   I'd certainly ride that tyre.

Comment: I have gotten 2 flats in about a year. I mainly ride on the street. @Criggie